# Any ideas how to get text from flash object with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, flash

I am trying to get Artist and Song from http://musicovery.com/ . The whole thing is flash app, and I managed to get source with IE(couldn't access it via firefox, chrome, ctrl+u disabled on this page).

So I need an idea how to approach this. Is it even possible? First I tried to access object parameter values. This is the flash object I am talking about:

```
<noscript>
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
        id="musicovery" width="100%" height="100%"
        codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/swflash.cab">
        <param name="movie" value="musicovery.swf&ctprec=si&idsong=&codeartist=&ccartist=&mood=&energy=&tempo=&dance=&type=&tag=&offre=&code=&link=&userid=" />
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
        <param name="bgcolor" value="#f0f0f0" />
        <param name="wmode" value="opaque"  />
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
        <!--<param name="flashvars" value="&ctprec=si&idsong=&codeartist=&ccartist=&mood=&energy=&tempo=&dance=&type=&tag=&offre=&code=&link=&userid=" />-->
        <embed src="musicovery.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#f0f0f0"
            width="100%" height="50%" name="musicovery" align="middle"
            wmode="opaque"
            play="true"
            loop="false"
            quality="high"
            allowScriptAccess="sameDomain"
            type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
            pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
        </embed>
</object>
```

I tried to use this:

```
alert($('object#musicovery').find('param[name="movie"]').val());
```

It says it's undefined, so I can't even access this.

I need some tips :)

Thanks!

Comment: Your code works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/7rVZj/

Comment: It is possible, but it's going to require the flash sending the content to javascript rather than javascript going to the flash to get the content.

Comment: That is not the option, because the thing is not mine :) Which means it is not possible?

Comment: @JohnMathilda with available client-side technologies, yes i'd go with not possible. server-side though opens up a lot of possibilities.